# Using =image() on worksheet, and then printout using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the google API to produce QR codes using the =image() function.

I am in need of a tidy way to allow the image to load before the VBA continues running. Currently the code I have runs before the image loads leaving that part of the printout with the loading symbol.

```
dim ws as worksheet
ws = sheet("Sheet1")
ws.range("A1") = 5 ' this is the change made for the image to change
doevents
ws.printout copies:= 2
```

I could use `application.wait()`, but I am wondering if anyone has any other ideas.

Thanks